# Elixir - HMAC decode or validate

Tags: elixir

Here we can encode using hmac by

```
:sha256
|> :crypto.hmac("key444", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
|> Base.encode16
```

But how we can decode are validate the data again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I decrypt a HMAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218925/how-can-i-decrypt-a-hmac)

Comment: To validate, just pass the new string to the same code and compare the result?