# How to decript password using nodejs or javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-crypto

Tried to see my password from my database.My password is test123 So in my database i have saved like this : $2a$10$0V1JkVfl8n.WD/QbInIWqubjcaxnCCnP3K.bhuxjAQbJ9LyFiNTdu. How to see my password again like test123 from $2a$10$0V1JkVfl8n.WD/QbInIWqubjcaxnCCnP3K.bhuxjAQbJ9LyFiNTdu.

Can we do using nodejs or javascript?

```
    var crypto = require("crypto");
    var password = '$2a$10$0V1JkVfl8n.WD/QbInIWqubjcaxnCCnP3K.bhuxjAQbJ9LyFiNTdu';  
    var algorithm = "aes-192-cbc"; //algorithm to use
     
    const key = crypto.scryptSync(password, 'salt', 24); //create key
    var text = '?????????????????????????"; //text to be encrypted

    const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0);
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
    var encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex'); // encrypted text

    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
    var decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, 'hex', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');  

    console.log(decrypted);  //Output should be like test123
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's meant to be decrypted on purpose.

**"Cryptographic hash functions are a special type of one-way calculation"**

> What is hashing?
>
> Cryptographic hash functions are a special type of one-way
> calculation. They take a string of data of any size and always give an
> output of a predetermined length. This output is called the hash, hash
> value or message digest. Since these functions don’t use keys, the
> result for a given input is always the same.

---

[**Encryption, hashing, salting – what’s the difference?**](https://www.comparitech.com/blog/information-security/encryption-hashing-salting/)

StackOverflow question:

> "HMAC is a MAC/keyed hash, not a cipher. It's not designed to be
> decrypted. If you want to encrypt something, use a cipher, like AES,
> preferably in an authenticated mode like AES-GCM.
>
> The only way to "decrypt" is guessing the whole input and then
> comparing the output."

[**How can I decrypt a HMAC?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14218987/11317072)

Comment: Getting confusion

Comment: @PappaS See updated answers with references the wording.

Comment: Instead of using code formatting for text you are quoting please use the quote formatting. Insert a `>` at the start of the line, use two spaces at the end of the line to insert a line break and continue the quote.

Answer (score 0):

All these encrypting algorithms are trying NOT to do exactly what you are asking for :). It's a one way process. That means there is no well-known library in javascript or nodejs world to easily decrypt your password. Maybe there might be some applications, just using try-and-error method to guess your password.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Your password had the following functions applied.

- Saved value = HASH(`Password` + `salt`)

That can't be undone.